# Do items despawn in Vampire Survivors?

Tags: vampire-survivors

Do items ever despawn in Vampire Survivors? I sometimes leave XP gems behind while trying to avoid enemies. Sometimes I'm able to come back to collect the gems later on, but other times I have trouble finding them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/VampireSurvivors/comments/sidzlq/do_xp_orbs_and_chest_despawn/):

> XP gems never despawn. When you get too far away from them, the gems are grouped up, often into reds.